# What is the difference between 'CREATE USER [user_name] FOR LOGIN [login_name]' and 'CREATE USER [user_name] FROM LOGIN [login_name]'

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I see some people using

```
CREATE USER [user_name] FOR LOGIN [login_name]
```

and others using

```
CREATE USER [user_name] FROM LOGIN [login_name]
```

What is the difference between key word `FOR` and `FROM` here?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the official [MS Documentation for `CREATE USER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), you'll see that you can use either `FOR` or `FROM` - they are equivalent - no difference:

```
-- Users based on Windows principals that connect through Windows group logins  
CREATE USER   
    { windows_principal [ { FOR | FROM } LOGIN windows_principal ]  
              | user_name { FOR | FROM } LOGIN windows_principal  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought they were different, like the `ADD | DROP` key words in [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)